# Is it a no-no to have one presenter call a method on another presenter in a Model-View-Presenter application?

Tags: winforms, mvp

I have a presenter that recenters a view. It is `BTCanvasPresenter` which has a reference to a view called a `BTCanvas`.

I'm making another presenter, `MainMenuPresenter`, which deals with the menu strip items. One menu item recenters the `BTCanvas`. The menu events used to be in the form of the main window. I'm moving them to MainMenuPresenter.

So my question is, should `MainMenuPresenter` call `RecenterView` on `BTCanvasPresenter`? Should `BTCanvasPresenter` handle that menu event? Should `MainMenuPresenter` get a reference to `BTCanvas` so it can call the view's `Recenter` method itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is ok to have a presenter listen to more than one view/model, but try not to have the presenters call each other, it doesn't lead to an intuitive design.